# Force CI segmentation to skip first segment

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

We have a website that has been running for a year.

Recently the team is introducing 2 new languages and therefore we are changing everything to include in the address bar something like /en or /ru

Therefor what once was:
http://www.website.com
is now http://www.website.com/en

The only problem is we need to go through every single page and change

`$this->uri->segment(x)` to `$this->uri->segment(x+1)`

Is there a way to tell CI that /en is perhaps part of the `base_url()` and therefore keep `$this->uri->segment(x)` as it was before and just skip the /en part?

Thank you.

Comment: are you using CI 3 ?

Comment: Please post your routes code.

Comment: I am using CI3 and i18n (with a few fixes to make it work for CI3)


`// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(en|fa)/(.+)$'] = "$2";

// '/en', '/de', '/fr' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|fa)$'] = $route['default_controller'];`

Answer (score 1):

in config > config

do this

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.website.com/en;
```

Comment: I have already done this. Because the files are not actually inside the /en folder it is not considering it as a separate item.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your parameter as an argument to the function instead uri segment,

```
function page_details( $id = 0 )
{
    // do something with $id
}
```

This never breaks, however you change your base url, works for below all,

```
http://www.website.com

http://www.website.com/en

http://www.website.com/ru/new
```